# the team had held off

Tags: phrase-meaning

Is it clear to you that the phrase "the team had held off"probably means "the NCBI had stayed away (stopped responding or something similar)"?  I am not sure what it means.

> Zhang asked Holmes for a minute to think, but the flight attendant was telling him to hang up. He reflected on the grim conversations he’d had in Wuhan. “It was getting serious,” he recalls. “I said, ‘Eddie, I authorize you to release the data.’” Holmes posted it on the website virological.org, and Zhang asked the NCBI to release the genome. Holmes says **the team had held off** because of the government order, but Zhang says he wasn’t aware of the edict at the time. He does say, however, that he realized some health officials might be angry if he posted the sequence online.

> Source:  Nature  [Nature’s 10: ten people who helped shape science in 2020](https://www.nature.com/immersive/d41586-020-03435-6/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context,

> To hold off = to not do something immediately:
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hold-off)

Hence, the team delayed acting.